# What is the name of this notation for sum?

Tags: notation, education

In my kid's school (age 6) they are using a variation of cuisenaire rods to learn mathematics. When they are doing the operations on paper the notation used is this one:[image], it's designed to ressemble the usage the make of the rods.
I'm curious about the name it has and to look into references on it.

Comment: I don't know that this has a name...it seems like a standard device to do arithmetic mentally. $17=10+7$, $15=10+5$ so $17+15=10+10+7+5=20+12=32$.  I don't suppose that writing it graphically the way you present it here is terribly helpful...it all looks a bit hard to unpack.

Comment: You might have better luck on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called addition by partitioning. One can partition a number into its digits, tens, etc. and then add these seperately.

Comment: +1 Indeed, that seems to be the right jargon. For a technique, even!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is just what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Is the notation important?

To me, this looks like a graphical description of an arithmetic technique called *adding from left to right*.

It seems to outline that process. It is an old mental arithmetic strategy. After you master this technique, no notation is necessary. So that is why I question the importance of knowing what the notation is.

I first saw this in the first chapter somewhere  of *How to Calculate  Quickly* by Henry Sticker.

Comment: It might be helpful for reference, if you work in education. No need to question the legitimacy of the question. ;-)

Comment: @MarsPlastic I didn’t question the legitimacy of the question, just the focus. I am betting the person will get better results with the name of the technique rather than the name of the notation.

Comment: Okay, I see your point now. Your answer sounded a little discouraging to me at first.

Comment: @MarsPlastic It's possible that the poster doesn't even make a distinction between notation and technique. But one really ought to :/

Answer (score 0):

It is worthy to note that, in spite of the particular way we write it, the name of the properties which make the notation work is [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property):

\begin{align*}
17+15&=(10+7)+(10+5)\tag{by the definition of 17 and 15}\\
&=(10+7+10)+5\tag{by the associativity}\\
&=(10+10+7)+5\tag{by the commutativity}\\
&=(10+10)+(7+5)\tag{by the associativity}\\
&=20+12\tag{by the definition of 20 and 12}\\
\end{align*}